# Follow a curved path with an Image

Tags: animation, windows-8, microsoft-metro, expression-blend

I am trying to follow a path with an image in a Windows Store App. I want the image to follow that path and rotate while it follows it. Think in a plane doing a curve or something like [this](http://www.charlespetzold.com/silverlight/UnicycleMan/UnicycleMan.html).

Among tutorials for silverlight/wpf, I have found several things that I don't have in a windows store app, such as: [DoubleAnimationUsingPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746981.aspx) or [MatrixAnimationUsingPath](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/11/250534.html) or even [PathListBox](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/pathlistbox/motionpath.aspx).

I have also tried to do that animation in Blend (although my experience in the windows world is small, the experience in blend is worse) but I can't even do [Path -> Make Layout Path](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/pathlistbox/motionpath.aspx).

How can I do the something like the [unicycle animation](http://www.charlespetzold.com/silverlight/UnicycleMan/UnicycleMan.html) in a windows metro app?

**EDIT**

I want to use a path because I want to generate those paths randomly. Doing key frames in blend by hand works for a specific controlled path. However, generate those key frames randomly seems a lot more work that simply generate a random arc path that can be followed.

Comment: Please check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251977/how-to-draw-an-arc-in-winrt-with-animation

Comment: I thought in doing the animation using key frames. However, I am trying to animate into a path because I will generate those paths randomly. I belive that generationg key frames randomly will give a lot more work that generating a curve path randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up porting the Petzold solution (the solution Hermit Dave gave and that I was trying to avoid).

However, I had to do some changes.

I passed the "xFormUnicycleMan" `MatrixTransform` as a depdendency property of the `MatrixAnimationUsingPath` with:

```
TargetElement="{Binding ElementName=xformUnicycleMan}"
```

Then, in the `OnCompositionTargetRendering` I get it and I have modified the values I need to take using the following:

```
MatrixTransform matrixTransform = this.TargetElement as MatrixTransform;
PropertyPath targetProperty = new PropertyPath("MatrixProperty");
PropertyInfo fieldInfo = 
    matrixTransform.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty(targetProperty.Path);  
DependencyProperty dependencyProp = 
    fieldInfo.GetValue(matrixTransform) as DependencyProperty;
```

Thanks for the help provided from @Miek.

If someone has a better solution I would apreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Charles Petzold posted his hacked MatrixAnimationUsingPath here

http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/11/250534.html

Download the source (zip file) and port it

Comment: I saw that (it is one of the links in my question) but it seems kinda overkill. I mean, it has to be a simpler way. Also, everytime I tried to port something to windows metro apps (consdering I have 0 experience in other microsoft technologies) I get a lot of problems.

Comment: unfortunately they started Windows 8 xaml with a clean slate which means they brought little from SL / WPF and as a result many things are missing. Porting is never easy.. I occasionally port things and its a hit and miss

Comment: my bad.. checked the first link and saw msdn and assumed the same for second :)

Comment: I ended up porting that solution. Wasn't that hard thanks to @Miek.

Comment: sometimes ( more often with win8dev ) you have to get your hands dirty. good luck