# Drawing shapes inside XAML?

Tags: xaml, animation, loading, expression-blend

I want to have an animation to show how an"8" is drawn in Windows Phone app, inside xaml / expression blend, what would be the best approach to do this, the only way I can think of is making a few pictures of the "8" at different stages, and inside expression blend create a storyboard, and add a new picture of the "8" every few seconds.

Any tips on a better approach or tutorial would help a lot,

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this reply:

[How to draw an arc in winRT with animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251977/how-to-draw-an-arc-in-winrt-with-animation/14259458#14259458)

The question says WinRT, but its the same for WP

Too many images to re-do the reply here :)